# Не могу отправить несколько фото через telegram api методом SendMediaGroup python

Tags: php, python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Как отправить несколько фото через telegram api?
Вот метод https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMediaGroup
Или же с помощью библиотеки aiogram, уже все перепробовал, но выдает ошибку сериализации JSON объекта, не могу понять в чем причина

Вот объект который передаю:

```
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendMediaGroup".format(settings.__telegram_token)
files = {"chat_id": "ID",
         "media": [
               {"type": "photo", "media": "attach:\/\/data.jpg"},
               {"type": "photo", "media": "attach:\/\/data.jpg"}
              ],
                "data1.jpg": open("data.jpg", "rb"),
                "data.jpg": open("data.jpg", "rb")}

response = requests(url, files=files).json()
```

Но в итоге ошибка -> **TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable.**
Нашел также реализацию отправки на php и все нормально, без ошибок

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . "TOKEN" . "/sendMediaGroup";
    
 $postContent = [
            'chat_id' => "ID",
            'media' => json_encode([
                ['type' => 'photo', 'media' => 'attach://data.jpg' ],
                ['type' => 'photo', 'media' => 'attach://data.jpg' ],
            ]),
            'data1.jpg' => new CURLFile(realpath("/var/www/html/data.jpg")),
            'data.jpg' => new CURLFile(realpath("/var/www/html/data.jpg")),
        ];
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postContent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data']);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вчитайтесь в текст ошибки. Вы не можете превратить `BufferedReader` в json. В json запросе нельзя прикреплять файлы. Смотрите как сделано в примере на PHP - отправляйте используя `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: да, уже нашел решение проблемы, стандартными средствами библиотеки понял как это сделать, оказывается надо было отправлять список InputMediaPhoto()

Answer (score 0):

Вы `media` передаёте массивом, а нужна json-строка (посмотрите внимательнее на аналог кода PHP).

Comment: попробовал, но пришел ответ от сервера: {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: media to send are not specified'}

Comment: а это нормально, что вы передаёте `data1.jpg` и `data.jpg`, а ссылаетесь только на `data.jpg`?

Comment: По факту да, т.к если сделать одинаковые ключи в словаре, обрабатываться будет только один

Comment: нет, я про то, что массив в `media` содержит полностью одинаковые элементы... И ещё у меня есть некоторые сомнения в формировании запроса. В python не силён, но сами файлы должны быть не в json-теле запроса, а как отдельные файлы, добавленные в виде `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Вообще параметр "files" в методе requests.post() автоматически формирует multipart/form-data из словаря, я таким образом через api метод sendPhoto отправлял одну фотографию, но вот для нескольких нужен метод sendMediaGroup, но запрос не понятно как сформировать и в документации нету примера, и не особо понятно как работать с этим методом, к тому же в инете один единственный код на php нашел и все. Вот думаю единственное, что отличается в коде на php, это "data.jpg": new CURLFile(realpath(file_path)), может из-за этого, т.к остальное в полном соответствии

Comment: попробуйте в массиве `media` у одного из объектов установить `media` в `attach://data1.jpg`. Ну вдруг...

Comment: Не, не выходит (9(( Ладно, думаю легче на php позже код переписать, если обязательно понадобится отправка нескольких фото, а так пока что по одному. И все равно спасибо))0)

Comment: Если ещё не победил, попробуй отправить запросы с PHP и Python на адрес https://raw.ddrv.ru (только токены-ключи замени на фейковые и вместо картинок текстовые файлы). Сервер вернёт тебе сформированный запрос в сыром виде. Можешь в вопрос добавить результаты, посмотрим разницу